Boolean not changing across all instances of a script
I'm creating a script for a turn-based battle system.
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(inBattle == true && battleStart == true)
        {
            if (renderer.tag == "Player" && isStunned == true)
            {
                print(renderer.transform.name + " is stunned!");
                alreadyChosen = true;
            }
            if (renderer.tag == "Player" && alreadyChosen == false && isPlayerTurn == true && isStunned == false)
            {
                print(renderer.transform.name);
                characterChosen = true;
                alreadyChosen = true;
            }
            else if (renderer.tag == "Player" && characterChosen == true)
            {
                print("Thanks");
                characterChosen = false;
                alreadyChosen = true;
                actionsMade++;
            }
            if (renderer.tag == "Enemy" && characterChosen == true)
            {
                print("Hit!");
                characterChosen = false;
                actionsMade++;
            }
            if (actionsMade >= 3)
            {
                isPlayerTurn = false;
                alreadyChosen = false;
                actionsMade = 0;
            }
        }
    }

After all 3 party members take their actions, both isPlayerTurn and actionsMade reset across all instances. However, alreadyChosen only resets on one instance, or sometimes not at all. The two that work are static variables, but alreadyChosen isn't. If I do make it static, then it would make the player only able to make one action total. I tried putting the alreadyChosen variable elsewhere, and that didn't work. Please help.

Please add more tags; what programming language and what game framework?

Should These all be exclusive code blocks? -> use else if! Currently it is possible that one block sets the value of a bool flag which might then further result in a following if block also being executed as the condition might match now after the first block has changed the flag(s)

For instance if (renderer.tag == "Player" && isStunned == true) -> you set alreadyChosen = true; so further below else if (renderer.tag == "Player" && characterChosen == true) also matches ...

@derHugo For some reason I can't see the full comment, how would I fix that?
